# how many nodes can be managed by chef-server?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to know how many nodes can be bootstrap and maintained by open source chef server. I am using open source chef server. and I did bootstrap more than 40 nodes but status of 20 nodes only monitored and display by open source chef server. Is there any limitation on number of nodes on open source  chef server.
  Why open source chef-server shows 20 nodes out of 40 in status option, but all the node added to chef server.

Comment: To show more than 20 node in status option of open source chef server follow this link https://github.com/opscode/chef-server-webui/pull/11 It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a limitation of that particular part of the Chef Server webui. The "status" page performs a search, but the displayed results are truncated. It's a bug, [CHEF-3883](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3883), which has been marked as committed, so it will be available in an upcoming release of the open source Chef Server.

The actual number of nodes that the Open Source Chef Server can manage is far, far greater. For example, [Cycle Computing](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/02/04/cycle-computing-puts-chef-11-through-its-paces-w10k-aws-servers/) and [Facebook](http://www.getchef.com/press-releases/facebook-likes-opscode-and-private-chef/) have built clusters of > 10,000 machines with a Chef Server. Phil Dibowitz of Facebook [spoke at ChefConf](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYZ2GzYAw_Q), and other technical conferences, last year about their use of Chef.